# For Federal Crimes, where does the money collected from penalties go?

Tags: penalty, government

Today it was [announced](http://www.reuters.com/article/2014/04/09/us-poland-hp-idUSBREA380EZ20140409) that Hewlett-Packard, HP, has to pay a $108 million dollar penalty to the Department of Justice, DoJ, for pleading guilty to bribery and money laundering. My question is,  where does the money go when it is collected by the DoJ? SEC?

Comment: Having some difficulty seeing the connection to personal finance here.

Comment: @JohnFx I agree, but I didn't know what other site to post it to. Since this site deals with "& money", I felt it was on topic. Feel free to move.

Comment: @Scott - "Feel free to move." This assumes that stack exchange has a site that this would be on topic for, not every topic is covered by the SE network.

Comment: We'll likely be removing the "& Money" part.

Comment: @NathanL "not every topic is covered by the SE network"  sounds like something we should work on :)

Comment: @Scott, if you know several people with expertise in economics, you should invite them to join you: http://area51.stackexchange.com/

Comment: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61732/economics

Answer (score 2):

The SFGate had an article on this a few years ago:

http://www.sfgate.com/business/networth/article/When-government-fines-companies-who-gets-cash-3189724.php

"Civil penalties, often referred to as fines, usually go to the U.S. Treasury or victims."

Short answer in the case you references it would be the US Treasury. In cases where there is a harmed party then they would get something to account for their loss. But it can get complicated depending on the crime.